# How can i disable task scheduler jobs using powershell script

Tags: powershell

i'am looking for a powershell script that can be run to disable Task Scheduler job(internally disabling a .bat file) which can disable between the timestamps that we mention to the script. Is it doable using a Powershell script?

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

I would start off by using the handy-dandy SCHTASKS executable with CSV format output to get an object back with all your scheduled task information:

```
$tasks = & SCHTASKS /Query /V /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

The magic decoder ring of parameters: /Query is the operation, /V is verbose output, /FO CSV is the output format. Now that it is in an object, you can easily filter to find the task(s) you are looking for:

```
$task = $tasks | ? { $_.TaskName -eq "My Batch File" }
```

Which then makes it easy to enable or disable a task, again using the SCHTASKS executable:

```
& SCHTASKS /Change /DISABLE /TN "$Task.TaskName"
```

You can easily enable the task again with the same code, just replacing the /DISABLE with /ENABLE. SCHKTASKS is a very powerful tool to use for creating and manipulating scheduled tasks.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357.aspx

Comment: hi Goyuix, i'am pretty new to Poweshell, so you are asking me to provide a csv file in step 2 having all the batch files that i wanted to disable? could you please help me start through the actual code

Comment: Step 1 generates the CSV, and stores it in the $tasks variable. Step 2 just uses the $tasks variable from step 1 as a source of data, and applies a filter to get task records with a TaskName equal to "My Batch File" - you would want to replace the name with whatever is appropriate for your script.

Comment: Great!! it worked, But the script is asking me `Please enter the run as password for server\userid` Is there a way we can bypass this step and can disable the task?

Answer (score 1):

With Windows Server 2008 & newer, you can use `SCHTASKS` or the COM object `Schedule.Service` to manipulate tasks in a more object-oriented way. See http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/create-scheduled-task-by-using-powershell/ for a examples of using both `SCHTASKS` and `Schedule.Service`. Task Scheduler's COM interface is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383608(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 0):

only Windows 2012 / 8.1 and above
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816%28v=wps.630%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Goyuix answer fails on localized windows: TaskName is "Nombre de tarea". Built my own script for win7 or later (powershell 3 doesn't have newer TaskSchd functions). First part makes a dummy task to extract localized names. Then extracts all Enabled tasks. Make a $toDisableArr matching a blacklist to delete. Finally remove tasks notmatching whitelist tasks we want to keep. Remove last comment sign # to actually do the job.

```
  # International aware disable SchdTasks:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force  #needs admin rights

  # This is the RegEx match blacklist of tasks to disable any update/upload/telemetry/report, etc
$blackList="update|upload|telemetry|report|experience|schedule|sync|^\\{|\\AC"+
"|\\ASUS|^\\ATK|^\\AVGPCTun|^\\Acer|\\Ad|\\App|Overseer|^\\BacK|\\Blue|^\\ByteF"+
"|^\\CCl|^\\CL|^\\Creat|^\\Dash|^\\Easy|^\\Egis|^\\EPSON|^\\FubT|\\HP|\\Intel"+
"|\\Lenovo|\\Off|^\\Priv|\\.NET|\\Auto\|\\Broker|\\Clip|\\Cu|\\Dev|\\Diagn|\\Disk"+
"|\\DUSM|\\EDP|\\Enterpr|\\Error|\\Feedb|\\File|\\Flight|\\Hello|\\Input|\\Inst"+
"|\\Inter|\\Lang|\\License|\\Locat|\\Ma|\\Mobil|\\MUI|\\Net|\\Nla|\\Perf|\\PI"+
"|\\Pow|\\Push|\\RA|\\Re|\\Se|\\Sh|\\Side|\\Softw|\\Sp|\\St|\\Subs|\\Sysmain"+
"|\\TP|\\UN|\\UPnP|\\USB|\\User|\\WC|\\WD|\\Windows Activ|\\Windows Defender Ver"+
"|\\Windows Filt|\\WindowsBack|\\WindowsCol|\\Winin|\\Wlan|\\WOF|\\Work|\\Wwan"+
"|\\Xbl|^\\Mini|^\\Mir|^\\Mo|^\\Ne|^\\Norton WSC|^\\np|^\\Nv|^\\OIns|^\\Opt"+
"|^\\PD|^\\Qu|^\\Rt|^\\Sams|^\\SCC|^\\Smart|\\Sony|^\\Swe|^\\Sym|^\\Tun"+
"|^\\Ubt|^\\UMon|^\\wat|^\\Ya"

  # This is the RegEx match whitelist of tasks that won't be disabled
$whiteList="\\AppListB|\\CertificateServ|\\Chkdsk|\\Data Int|\\DirectX"+
"|\\MemoryDiag|\\SystemSound|\\PI\\Secure|\\Plug |\\Printing|\\Registry"+
"|\\SystemRestore|\\Task Manager|\\IpAddressC|\\MsCtfMonitor|\\Time |\\sihpost"

  # can't use "$?" no good if 2>null, use $LastExitCode instead
SCHTASKS /query /tn isidummy >null 2>&1
  # if exist delete it
if ($lastexitcode -eq 0) { SCHTASKS /delete /tn isidummy /f >null 2>&1}
  # create dummy enabled task to extract localized names
SCHTASKS /create /sc monthly /tn isidummy /tr clip.exe >null 2>&1
  # $tarea[0] localized headers: [1] "TaskName"; [11] "Scheduled Task State"
$tarea=SCHTASKS /query /tn isidummy /v /fo csv
  #[0] has headers names array
$campos = ($tarea[0] -split ',')
  # Local names of "TaskName"; "Scheduled Task State" (may use .Trim('"') to remove "
$localTN=$campos[1]; $localSchedState=$campos[11]
  #tarea[1] has isidummy values
$campos = ($tarea[1] -split ',')
  # local name of "Enabled"
$localEnabled=$campos[11]
  # remove auxiliary dummy task
SCHTASKS /delete /f /tn "isidummy" >null 2>&1
  # Write localized names (ie SPA): "Nombre de tarea""Estado de tarea programada""Habilitado"
"Localized Names: " + $localTN + $localSchedState + $localEnabled

  # this will find all enabled tasks, $localXXX will be replaced with localized names here:
$docommand= "`$tareas=SCHTASKS /Query /V /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | where-object {`$_.$localSchedState -eq $localEnabled }"
  # SPA will execute: $tareas=SCHTASKS /Query /V /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv | where-object { $_."Estado de tarea programada" -eq "Habilitado"}
Invoke-Expression $docommand
  # extract all tasknames as a single string
$nombres=$tareas | Select-Object -Property $localTN.trim('"') | out-string
  # "convert to array of strings separating in NewLines, first 3 lines are headers
$nombres= $nombres -split "\n", 0, "multiline"
  # remove header strings (first 3 items), and duplicates
$nombres= $nombres[3..$nombres.count] | sort -unique
  # fill toDisableArr array from allTasks ($nombres) matching blacklist
$toDisableArr= @();
foreach ($tarea in $nombres) {
  if ($tarea -match $blackList) { $toDisableArr+= $tarea.TrimEnd() }
}
  # parse toDisableArr, excluding whitelisted items
foreach ($tarea in $toDisableArr) {
  if ($tarea -notmatch $whiteList) {
    echo $tarea
    # SCHTASKS /change /disable /tn $tarea
  }
}
```

Comment: To disable locked tasks we can use NirSoft AdvancedRun.exe, just replace last command with:    $doArguments= "/EXEFilename `"$env:windir\System32\SCHTASKS.EXE`" /CommandLine '/change /disable /tn `"$tarea`"' /RunAs 8 /Run" ;
      Start-Process "`"$env:SystemDrive\UT\AdvancedRun.exe`"" $doArguments